# Simple question about random walk with stopping time

Tags: probability, probability-theory

> I was reading a book and stuck with one line as follows:
>   $$\sum_{m=1}^\infty E[X_m] P(T \ge m) = EX_1 ET$$
>   where $\{X_m\}$ is i.i.d. with $EX_m < \infty$   and $T$ be discrete stopping time with $ET < \infty$

I know $X_m$ is i.i.d. hence $EX_m = EX_1$ and can be taken out of the summation, but I still confused how to make the last equality hold?

$$\sum_{m=1}^\infty E[X_m] P(T \ge m) = E[X_1]\sum_{m=1}^\infty  P(T \ge m) = ? =EX_1 ET$$

> I think my question is why $\sum_{m=1}^\infty  P(T \ge m) =  ET ? $

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that:

$$P(T \geq 1)=P(T=1)+P(T=2)+P(T=3)+P(T=4)+\cdots$$

$$P(T \geq 2)=P(T=2)+P(T=3)+P(T=4)+P(T=5)\cdots$$

$$P(T \geq 3)=P(T=3)+P(T=4)+P(T=5)+P(T=5)+\cdots$$

$$P(T \geq 4)=P(T=4)+P(T=5)+P(T=6)+P(T=7)+\cdots$$

The same for other $m$. If you add this equalities side by side you get:

$$P(T \geq 1)+P(T \geq 2)+P(T \geq 3)+P(T \geq 4)+\cdots=P(T=1)+2P(T=2)+3P(T=3)+4P(T=4)+\cdots=E[T]$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** using the Fubini theorem,
$$
E[T] = E\left[\sum_{m=1}^\infty 1_{m\le T} \right]
= \sum_{m=1}^\infty E\left[1_{m\le T} \right]
$$

Answer (score 0):

The equality can be proved with the so called *integrating the tail* method for non negative random variables. Look [here](https://www.google.de/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&ei=5zxdVOqMBMHaOLb_geAN&url=http://www.columbia.edu/~ks20/4701-10/4701-10-Notes-1.pdf&ved=0CCEQFjAA&usg=AFQjCNF3RpiY1yb2wGcMjDKIlB_CKbpghQ) (page 8, Proposition 1.1) for the proof of the continuous case (the discrete proof is similar).